# Reading from input device in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, io, linux-device-driver

I am trying to read events from an input device in ruby.

However

```
File.open('/dev/input/event9').read 16
```

returns an exception :

```
Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ io_fread - /dev/input/event9
from (pry):1:in `read'
```

The signature for the read method in IO [documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/IO.html#method-i-read) explain the reference to fread method (read in ruby calls the corresponding fread in C).

However the EINVAL errors seems to refer to a bad advice sent to the input device but I don't really understand.

In an effort to understand the issue, I have chowned to file to give users group perm without any luck.

My question is: what does that "Invalid argument" error means in my situation ?

Comment: using ruby 2.1.2 on arch by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to `man 2 read`, which is the system call behind `fread` which failed.

```
   EINVAL fd is attached to an object which is unsuitable for reading;  or
          the  file  was  opened  with  the  O_DIRECT flag, and either the
          address specified in buf, the value specified in count,  or  the
          current file offset is not suitably aligned.
```

Which means basically that the driver attached to `/dev/input/event9` isn't happy with the operation requested. In your case it's probably due to alignment issues (wrong read size), see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt for details about the event protocol and how event devices should be read.

Comment: input documentation does give any advice regarding size. However a simple loop over possible size reveal 24 and its multiples. I guess I need to use that one. thanks!

Comment: 24 seems weird for an event structure which contain 2 int for time, 2 short for code+type and 1 int for value. the read size should 16